# change of basis $S$ to $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

$$
S = (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)\\
T = (1,1,-1), (1,1,1), (1,0,1)\\
f(x,y,x) = (x+y-z , x+2y+z , z)
$$

Could someone help me find the change in basis s[1]t and s[f]s

For the first one i tried putting them as a matrix next to each other but then didn't know where to go from there. 
I also tried putting alpha in front of each set of brackets but couldn't see how that was gaining me anything.

any help would be much appreciated thank you!!

edit: i have worked out that s[f]s is (1,1,0) (1,2,0) (-1,1,1)

Comment: In the first place, clarify what are s[1]t and s[f]s.

Comment: HINT.-$(1,0,0)=a(1,1,-1)+b(1,1,1)+c(1,0,1);\space a,b,c=?$. 

$a=\dfrac12$; $b=-\dfrac12$; $c=1$. Similarly with $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.